# Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?

Tags: php, mysql

Uma dúvida muito comum é por que devemos parar de usar funções do tipo mysql_* ? Por exemplo `mysql_query()`, ou `mysql_connect()`.

Vejo que muitas pessoas as usam, ou param de usar mas não sabem o real motivo. Por que elas deveriam parar de ser usadas uma vez que funcionam?

Comment: Essa funçao já se tornou obsoleta, sendo mais indicado o uso do mysqli_*

Answer (score 254, accepted):

#### Resumo

A resposta é uma só: não devemos usar funções da extensão "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido **descontinuado**; a extensão se tornou **obsoleta**, ou seja, **código que utilize essas funções não irá funcionar em futuras versões do PHP**.

---

#### Detalhes

Um usuário do site Stack Overflow em inglês escreveu:

> *There is no security problem with library itself but rather with library users* (**não há problemas de segurança com a biblioteca em si, mas sim com os usuários da biblioteca**).

A votação para descontinuar (*deprecate*) ou não, resultou em **25 votos a favor e 12 votos contra**. Foi uma boa maioria, mas não foi uma decisão unânime. Veja a [fonte oficial](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

Nessa mesma fonte, outro desenvolvedor escreveu:

> *The extension is not broken. The problem is the bad usage. It can be used safely, and good developers have been doing so for ages (**A extensão não tem defeitos.*** O problema é a má utilização. Ela pode ser usada com segurança, e bons desenvolvedores têm feito isso há anos).

A citação abaixo, também desse mesmo documento oficial, aponta para as **verdadeiras razões** para descontinuar a extensão:

> *ext/mysql is hard to maintain code. It is not getting new features.
>   Keeping it up to date for working with new versions of libmysql or
>   mysqlnd versions is work, we probably could spend that time better.*
>
> (A extensão mysql contém código de difícil manutenção. Não está
>   recebendo novas "features". Mantê-la atualizada para funcionar com
>   novas versões de libmysqld e mysqlnd é trabalhoso; nós poderíamos
>   estar usando melhor esse tempo.)

Em outras palavras: "**Para que ter um trabalhão para manter esse código velho?**" - pois na medida em que novas versões do MySQL (e suas "*client libs*") são lançadas, a extensão precisa ser atualizada...

...e, além disso, já existem as extensões **mysqli** (mais moderna) e a alternativa **PDO**... então... para que continuar mantendo? Vamos descontinuar? Aí, 25 votaram "sim", 12 votaram "não", e a decisão foi tomada.

---

#### Comentário Pessoal

Quando eu comecei com PHP não existia a extensão PDO. Eu usava a extensão "mysql", como a maioria, até que trabalhei num projeto usando "mysqli" e tomei conhecimento das vantagens, e sempre preferi a mesma desde então.

Logo depois, escrevi um par de classes que extendem as originais da extensão **mysqli**, e as utilizo até hoje em PHP puro, ou seja, quando não estou usando um *framework* como o Laravel, com seu "Fluent" e seu "Eloquent", o Symfony com "Doctrine", etc...

Para mim, acostumado até aos detalhezinhos de preparar cláusulas "LIKE" à prova de ataque, a "caixa preta" desses "prepared statements", "Active Record" ou "ORM" era vista com desconfiança. Essa fase passou, e hoje sou fã do Eloquent que vem com o Laravel 4...

---

#### Adendo

Após publicar toda a resposta acima, senti necessidade de frisar a importância do fator "**not getting new features**" na decisão por descontinuar a extensão. Quer dizer: apesar dela ser a mais rápida (melhor performance) na execução das tarefas simples, a ela faltam todo o leque de funcionalidades que as extensões alternativas (mysqli e PDO) contêm (*transactions*, suporte a SSL, *etc*) - ponto que foi destacado em outras respostas aqui.

Comment: Além de ser a melhor resposta, ainda traduz *deprecated* direito, +1

Comment: De http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation: "In mainstream English, the infinitive 'to deprecate' means, simply, 'to strongly disapprove of (something)'. Thus, for a standard document to state that a feature is deprecated is merely a recommendation against using it".

Comment: A partir do PHP 5.6 a utilização das funções mysql_* retornam erro de função depreciada. Então não há mais como utilizá-la a partir de então.

Comment: @touchmx correção: é possível usá-las sim no 5.6 simplesmente desligando o `deprecated errors`.

Comment: Quando li em sua resposta *12 votaram "não"* (pra 25) fiquei assustado, é uma quantidade de colaboradores considerável, então fui ler o link https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation#why_not_other_options - basicamente os argumentos eram sobre as mensagens irritantes, softwares lá fora pararem de funcionar (ou funcionarem mal devido aos possíveis aviso de *deprecated*) e tutoriais que ainda ensinam o uso do `mysql_`. Felizmente o "progresso" prevaleceu :) +1

Comment: Só pra ressaltar mesmo: o PHP 7 não tem mais o driver `mysql_`. Foi removido, pura e simplesmente. +1 Adorei a resposta!

Comment: Melhor resposta.

Answer (score 121):

Porque o uso das funções `mysql_*` foi desaprovado (*deprecated*) a partir do PHP 5.5 e, [segundo a documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php), as funções serão removidas em versões futuras do PHP, fazendo com que os programas que as utilizam parem de funcionar nessas versões.

### Limitações das funções `mysql_*`

Ao contrário das funções `mysqli_*`, as funções `mysql_*` não dão suporte a

- consultas assíncronas, não-bloqueantes
- consultas parametrizadas
- stored procedures
- transações

A falta de suporte a consultas parametrizadas significa que, ao usar funções `mysql_*` sem tomar certas precauções, seu programa está vulnerável a **ataques de injeção de SQL**, comprometendo a segurança e integridade dos dados. Exemplo:

```php
// consulta vulnerável a injeção de SQL
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id = $id")

// consulta parametrizada, variável $id é higienizada
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id = ?")
$query->bind_param("i", $id);
```

### Alternativas

Como alternativa, recomenda-se usar funções [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php), que superam as limitações já mencionadas das funções `mysql_*`.

Outra opção é usar [PDO (PHP Data Objects)](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php) que fornece uma camada de abstração de acesso a dados, o que significa que, independentemente de qual banco de dados você está usando, você pode usar as mesmas funções para emitir consultas e buscar dados.

### História

Para saber a história por trás da desaprovação das funções `mysql_*`, veja a [resposta de J.Bruni](/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql/4675#4675).

Comment: +1 pela menção do PDO como alternativa.

Comment: -1 Apesar de ter sido a resposta aceita, a primeira afirmação está errada: "ao usar funções `mysql_*`, seu programa está sujeito a ataques de injeção de SQL". Isto simplesmente não é verdade. É a má utilização dessas funções que pode criar vulnerabilidades, e não as funções em si. O 2º parágrafo também está incorreto: "deprecated" não significa "desaprovado" e a principal razão não foi a segurança, mas o trabalho em manter o código atualizado (desnecessário, por haver duas opções substitutas mais modernas: mysqli e PDO). E não é "possível" que serão removidas - é **certo** que serão.

Comment: Aconselho a ver [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/7210) do @J.Bruni.

Comment: Realmente, a falta de segurança é mais pelas mãos do desenvolvedor mal informado que coloca variáveis diretamente na query, sem nem sequer se preocupar com a entrada e saída de dados. O que também pode ser mal feito no mysqli.

Answer (score 61):

Não devemos mais usar mysql_* pelo seguinte motivo:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios SET nome='$nome';
```

O valor é passado diretamente na clausula sql, isso deixa a aplicação vulnerável a ataques de sql injection. Com pdo:

```
$con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios SET nome=?");
$con->bindParam(1, $nome);
$con->execute();
```

Ao utilizar pdo a consulta é preparada, passando por uma camada de proteção, camada essa que o mysql_* não possui, no momento de substituir os valores, essa camada de proteção entra em ação verificando se o comando está parecido com sql injection.

Comment: O erro também pode ser persistido pelo usuário no mysqli ou PDO.

Comment: A diferença é que a primeira versão não oferece essa vantagem, porém, o desenvolvedor pode criar uma tratativa dentro de um método para receber somente dados confiáveis.

Comment: Com o mysqli pode usar `$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO usuarios SET nome=\'$nome\'');` e continuar  vulnerável  igual.

Answer (score 53):

Por um motivo simples já é o suficiente para muitos:

Essa extensão do Mysql foi descontinuada pela equipe de desenvolvimento do PHP.
Mas dai você me pergunta, porque ela foi descontinuada uma vez que era simples e funcionava bacana?
Te digo:
Conforme o PHP está cada vez mais orientado a objeto e essa extensão do Mysql foi criada para o PHP estruturado, ela começou apresentar falhas no ambiente orientado a objetos.
Não suporta Stored procedure.
Não suporta transactions.
Só funciona com o Mysql até o 5.0.
... Entre outros. [Veja um comparativo aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Então um código com métodos mysql vai ter um deficit no futuro para suportar novas implementações e para corrigir futuros bugs. Utilizem o PHP PDO.

Comment: Vide documentação: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 47):

Vemos que temos muitas respostas sobre isso, mas resumindo, qualquer coisa que a versão mais recente no PHP (ou de qualquer linguagem) entre no estado de obsoleto, devemos alterar, tentar adequar o código e se possível usar recursos mais recentes que possam se tornar padrão no futuro e o PDO é um exemplo. 
Infelizmente tem programadores que acabam ignorando isso e só vão aprender e fazer as correções quando é feito alguma migração para um servidor ou alguma coisa do tipo que comece a acusar o erro.
Enfim, mudança necessária, cedo ou tarde precisaria ser feito e felizmente daqui um tempo usar PDO ou MySQLI vai ser como fazer um mysql_*

Answer (score 41):

Galera, apenas para fins didáticos, estou postando uma tabela contendo algumas informações importantes sobre o mysql, mysqli e PDO.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz uma pequena tradução na tabela, pode ser vista [aqui](http://barietoner.com.br/sac/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/olha-la-em.png), se tiver alguma coisa errada me avise. Alias, +1 por complementar todas as outras respostas

Comment: Espero ter ajudado com essa tabela pois ela mostra de forma bem objetiva e  resumidamente as vantagens e desvantagens dos mesmos.

Comment: Viu a tradução? Poderia colocar na sua resposta de forma alternativa como, Tabela traduzida em PT-BR e o link da imagem externa. Acredito que seria ainda mais útil

Comment: @VictorGomes O link do seu primeiro comentário está quebrado. Existe um link atualizado? Caso não exista, melhor excluir o comentário.